# LKM init module debugging.

Tags: kernel-module

I got the linux kernel and LKM to get debugged using KGDB. To debug the module I use add-symbol-file with the virtual address where the module is loaded in target machine. But with this approach I am unable to debug the init module because the virtual address can be found only after the module is loaded ie only after module_init is called.

So please can I know how to debug the init module?!?

Answer (score 1):

You could also set a breakpoint at do_one_initcall() and look at the address of mod->init to get the load address.